# Reading Properties file

Tags: java, maven

I Created a REST Web Service in Which I Created a config.properties file to store and retrieve some usernames and passwords through out the application. I stored it in /src/main/resources/config.properties.

when I tried to load it from my java code from eclipse it's working fine. but when I deployed it in tomcat it's not loading. the code i'm using to load the properties file is

```
properties.load(new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/config.properties"));
```

Can anyone help me how to resolve that issue

Comment: Creating a web service to retrieve usernames and passwords.... Don't forget to consider the security implications of what you're doing.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

What you deploy to Tomcat is a war file. Tomcat doesn't know or care about the directory where the *sources* of your application are.

The files in `src/main/resources` are copied to the `target/classes` directory by Maven, and this directory is then copied to the `WEB-INF/classes` directory of the deployed web application, which is in the classpath of your webapp. So you just need to load the file using the class loader:

```
properties.load(MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/config.properties"));
```

(MyClass being any class of your webapp).

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do it if your properties file is in WEB-INF/classes. In this case just write something like

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/name.properties"));
```

Obviously the file may be located in sub folder of classes. In this case you have to specify the full path when calling getResourceAsStream()

Comment: in my war file i can see that properties file in WEB-INF/classes. how can I access that ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to load it from the classpath:-

```
final Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/config.properties"));
```

Comment: @RJ What I have to include in propertiesPath?

Comment: That won't work. Tomcat doesn't know and care about the source directory used to build the deployed webapp. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you want to read a  example.properties  file located in /WEB-INF/props/example.properties in run time.

```
    Properties properties = new java.util.Properties();  
        InputStream inputStream =     
            getServletContext().getResourceAsStream("/WEB-INF/props/example.properties");  
properties.load(inputStream);
```

Now , we are ready to get value from example.properties file .

```
String value = properties.getProperty("propertyName");
```

Sample Properties File :

example.properties

propertyName  = 123